# Error issuer must use HTTPS (with TLS), or config value for property 'requireHttps' must be set to 'false' and allow HTTP (without TLS)

Tags: angular

I've trying to test my app, where I need to get a token from server, but when I login  this error appears in console.

[image]

This is the config that I'm using in environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  auth: {
    issuer: 'https://extraxxx.xxxxx', // URL of the Identity Provider
    clientId: 'xxxxx', // Client ID
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'https://localhost:4200/', // Redirect URL after logout
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + "/login-callback",
    silentRefreshRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/silent-refresh.html', // URL to redirect after silent refresh
    scope: 'openid profile logistack_apps authorization', // Scopes
    requireHttps: false,
    disableAtHashCheck: true,
    responseType: 'id_token token', // responseType
    preserveRequestedRoute: true, // preserve the requested route when redirecting
    oidc: true,
    showDebugInformation: true,
    clearHashAfterLogin: true,
    strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
  },
  url: "https://localhost:7152"
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. The config is set to false for requireHttps and you expect that. So, it seems to be working as designed or you are expecting something else which you have not added in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case the `issuer` and `clientId` was set incorrectly because I was fetching them from the `window.location.hostname` with `https`